# Blocks malicious website - Avast

Tags: windows-xp, virus, avast

Current System:
**Windows XP SP3, German**

There seems to be a virus on the system as Avast told. After this message the following steps were done:

- Remove all items from autostart using [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902%28v=msdn.10%29.aspx)
- Removed all unneeded applications by using [uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)
- Firefox uninstalled
- Internet Explorer uninstalled (only IE8 could be uninstalled)
- Thunderbird uninstalled
- [SpyBot](http://www.safer-networking.org/) installed and system scanned
- [Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) installed and scanned

[SpyBot](http://www.safer-networking.org/) comes without result. All is fine, no virus in this system.
[Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) has full trusted situation and also no virus found.

But [avast](http://www.avast.com) anti virus software throws messages when going to the internet by system Internet Explorer 6.0. Also avast blocks all webpages and connections. It is not possible to download any anti-virus software or anything else. In case there is no running software found in Task manager (all users visible) which are unknown, it seems to be a misterious situation.

I found similar questions but because internet is blocked by avast, people could not find any answer and no solution is available.

Could this message true or is it wrong?

[image: Avast message]

Comment: Sounds like Avast by default is blocking IE6 from access to the internet.  I would change the firewall rules to prevent this.

Comment: It is not advisable to run two antivirus systems simultaneously. If Security Essentials is running, uninstall Avast.

Comment: @Ramhound: Avast has replaced Firewall

Comment: @RandolphWest As you can read in the description, the other tools are only installed after avast detected the situation already, not by default.

Comment: @Nasenbaer - I am aware of that.  So modify the settings on Avast to allow IE6 access to the internet.  I strongly suggest not doing this for one simple fact, IE6 is not secure, there are unpatched vulerabilties that exist.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the [WinSock XP Fix](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/winsock_xp_fix.html) utility as it might solve your issue. When selling computers, I'm usually installing Avast! AV and WinSock XP helped mi numerous times to fix the XP issue when Avast! blocking browser HTTP access, so it may do the job for you as well. I'm not sure what changes this tool made, but it worked almost every time :)